# Problems with selction colomns

Tags: r, shiny, selection

when I try to change my filters in my sidebar I get the error: undefined columns selected

I used this sample for my coding: [sample](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html)

But what is wrong in my coding? Changing the colomns still works.

server.r

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output) 
  { 
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    db2out <- db2

    if (input$MetIDlist != "All") {
      db2out <- db2out[db2out$Metric.ID == input$MetIDlist]
    }
    if (input$TClist != "All") {
      db2out <- db2out[db2out$Technical.Criterion == input$TClist]
    }
    if (input$RTlist != "All") {
      db2out <- db2out[db2out$RT.Snapshot.name == input$RTlist]
    }
    if (input$Objectlist != "All") {
      db2out <- db2out[db2out$Object.type == input$Objectlist]
    }
    if (input$VioStlist != "All") {
      db2out <- db2out[db2out$Violation.status == input$VioStlist]
    }
    if (input$Critlist != "All") {
      db2out <- db2out[db2out$Critical.Y.N == input$Critlist]
    }
    if (input$Grouplist != "All") {
      db2out <- db2out[db2out$Grouping == input$Grouplist]
    }
    db2out[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]
  }))  
})
```

ui.r

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage
        (
          titlePanel("Dashboard"),
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              selectInput("MetIDlist", "Metric.ID",
                          c("All",
                            sort(unique(as.character(db2$Metric.ID))))),
              selectInput("TClist", "Technical Criterion",
                          c("All",
                            sort(unique(as.character(db2$Technical.Criterion))))),
              selectInput("RTlist", "Release",
                          c("All",
                            sort(unique(as.character(db2$RT.Snapshot.name))))),
              selectInput("Objectlist", "Objects",
                          c("All",
                            sort(unique(as.character(db2$Object.type))))),
              selectInput("VioStlist", "Violation Status",
                          c("All",
                            sort(unique(as.character(db2$Violation.status))))),
              selectInput("Critlist", "Critical",
                          c("All",
                            sort(unique(as.character(db2$Critical.Y.N))))),
              selectInput("Grouplist", "Group",
                          c("All",
                            sort(unique(as.character(db2$Grouping))))),
              conditionalPanel(condition="db2",
                selectizeInput("show_vars", "Spalten",
                                 names(db2), selected = names(db2), multiple = TRUE)),
              width = 2),
            mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("List", dataTableOutput("table")),
                tabPanel("Summary")
              )
            )
          )
        ))
```

my database db2 looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   5303 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Metric.ID          : num  7156 7220 7220 7220 7220 ...
 $ Metric.Name        : Factor w/ 99 levels "Avoid accessing data by using the position and length",..: 51 59 59 
 $ Technical.Criterion: Factor w/ 25 levels "Architecture - Multi-Layers and Data Access",..: 4 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
 $ RT.Snapshot.name   : Factor w/ 1 level "2017_RT12": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Violation.status   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Added","Deleted": 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Critical.Y.N       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Grouping           : Factor w/ 29 levels "281","Bes",..: 27 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Object.type        : Factor w/ 11 levels "Cobol Program",..: 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Object.name        : Factor w/ 3771 levels "[S:\\SOURCES\\",..: 3771 3770 3769 3768 3767 3
```

Could anyone give me a sample of a working solution or a hint?

Thanks

Comment: Can you narrow your question down?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you're subsetting you are trying to select from columns. You need a comma before the close square brackets.

e.g.

```
db2out <- db2out[db2out$Metric.ID == input$MetIDlist]
```

becomes

```
db2out <- db2out[db2out$Metric.ID == input$MetIDlist,]
```

That way you're selecting from rows rather than columns

Comment: Thanks for that advice. But when I do this there will be no output of my db2out at the end. The frame in my mainpanel is empty in that case.

Comment: when i delete [, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE] the frame will be shown, but I can't use the selecitzeInput

Comment: Just checking: You have some columns selected in input$show_vars? Put some prints before and after. E.g. print(head(db2out)); db2out<-db2out[input$show_vars]; print(head(db2out)); return(db2out)

Answer (score 0):

It works

At the end I changed the selecitzeinput statement in the ui.r

```
selectizeInput('e2', 'Auswahl', selected = names(db2), choices = names(db2), multiple = TRUE),
```

and the last statement in my server.r

```
db2out[, input$e2, drop = FALSE]
```